# Duplicate values in rows of SQL lite (Ionic 2)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-forms

code for creating table

```
  if (!this.isOpen) {
              this.storage = new SQLite();
              this.storage.create({ name: "form.db", location: "default" }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                this.db = db;
                db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS formstable (formId VARCHAR  PRIMARY KEY, clientId VARCHAR, formsdata VARCHAR)", []);
                console.log("table created successfully");
                this.isOpen = true;
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              })
            }
```

This is the function which i used to insert data to sql lite

```
 Savedata(formId:string, clientId:string,formsdata:string){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      let sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO formstable (formId, clientId,formsdata) VALUES (?,?,?)";
      this.db.executeSql(sql, [formId, clientId,formsdata]).then((data) =>{
        resolve(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log("data inserted successfully")
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

Function to get values from sql lite

```
 GetAlldata(){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM formstable", []).then((data) => {
        let arrayUsers = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0){
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              arrayUsers.push({
                formId: data.rows.item(i).formId,
                clientId: data.rows.item(i).clientId,
                formsdata: JSON.parse(data.rows.item(i).formsdata)
              });                         
          }                     
        }
        resolve(arrayUsers);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

My value **"formsdata"** in the table is a JSON ,which is converted to string and saving into database and parsing to json while getting.When everytime i called the function **"savadata()**" the three values(formid ,clientid, formsdata) inserted again and again.So how avoid this duplicate values, i tried **"Replace"** keyword but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the 'formId' a **primary key**. In your table schema change your necessary field to **primary key** so that the replace works.